# (SQL) How to set column names of MySQL table as the delimited first line of my infile?

Tags: mysql, import, load-data-infile

The first line of my infile is actually the name of the columns delimited in the file. Is there anyway for a mysql import to use those column names in the file, and create columns in the mysql table with those names so that I don't have to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can import structure using `LOAD DATA INFILE` if that's what you mean, but it shouldn't be that hard to write a parser to read that line and create a table in a general purpose language, and then you can use `IGNORE 1 LINES` in the `LOAD` statement to ignore the structure definition line on import.